# Pluralsight's "AWS Cloud Compute" skill does not have tags on the Stack Overflow badge

Tags: bug, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I passed the assessment for "AWS Cloud Compute" skill on Pluralsight.
I tried to add the badge of this to my Stack Overflow dev story.
I noticed that badge does not have any tags.
It is an issue because of badge without tags is skipped from Pluralsight IQ section.
Pluralsight support answered that they do not manage this.
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you're not surprised by those broken images!

Comment: @Nisarg It has less priority as for me.